# How to show downloaded html file in spring-boot application

Tags: html, spring-boot, iframe

I have a spring-boot application and I want to show pages which was saved in database as zip archive. It looks like on my [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW2nb.png). Many thanks for tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebMvcConfigurer with overrided method addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry):

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
```

where you can add folder with your data:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("**/your_folder/**").addResourceLocations("file:"+ "your_base_directory_where your_folder placed");
    }
```

Now you can open this page used by url

```
http://localhost:8787/your_base_directory_where your_folder placed/maybe_another_folder/your_folder/index.html
```

You can add new folders in your_base_directory in runtime and load it in your application.